# AttributeError from client sockets in python

Tags: python

I'm getting an attribute error from running the client side of the program, I'm pretty sure I did it everything correctly but apparently not.

Here's the code:

```
from socket import *
serverName = 'hostname'
serverPort = 12000
clientSocket = socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
message = raw_input('Input lowercase sentence:')
clientSocket.sendto(message,(serverName, serverPort))
modifiedMessage, serverAddress = clientSocket.recvfrom(2048)
print modifiedMessage
clientSocket.close()
```

This is the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "UDPClient.py", line 4, in <module>
    clientSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
AttributeError: type object '_socketobject' has no attribute 'socket'
```

EDIT:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "UDPClient.py", line 6, in <module>
    clientSocket.sendto(message,(serverName,serverPort))
socket.gaierror: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting this wrong. Since you `import *`, just use `AF_INET` and `SOCK_DGRAM`

```
>>> from socket import *
>>> clientSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
```

Tested on my machine using Py3.4

Comment: Since we're on this same code would you happen to know why I get the gaierror under the new 'EDIT'? I have a server name and same port as the server but it's giving me that socket.gaierror.

Comment: @user2318083 `serverName = '127.0.0.1'`, you aren't expecting `hostname` to work are you.

Comment: I fixed it but I did serverName = '' and it works also. @laike9m

Comment: @user2318083 The doc says: `the empty string represents INADDR_ANY`.